Access AWS database during Cloudbuild builds
How can I access an AWS MySQL database as part of a unit test that gets executed during a cloudbuild build on GCP?
I can access this database when I'm firing a cloud function with the cloud scheduler because I have a serverless VPC set up with an external static address, but if I'm mocking the cloud function inside a script that's running as part of the cloud build I don't see where you can configure things to use a vpc connector.
The only option in the cloudbuild.yml seems to be using a private worker pool. I was following some instructions which told me to set up a vpc peer network between GCP and AWS but I don't see how that's possible.
How is this typically done?

For unit testing/integration testing you could use docker containers, you can include MySQL as a service in the build steps, enabling you to run integration tests that require a MySQL database I like this approach because it was isolated. And yes you're right you can setup Private Worker Pool + VPN which is most secure and performant but requires the most setup, and another option would be setting up public internet access and its the simplest but exposes the database.
